# Determining the appropriate color range on a mask

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, mask

my task is to find the orange cube that is on the right without intersecting with the red one
[image: my task is to find the orange cube that is on the right without intersecting with the red one]

The view from camera.
[image: The view from camera.]

I try to find orange cube wit this color range.
[image: I try to find orange cube wit this color range.]

This is my code:

`````
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def nothing(*arg):
        passcv2.namedWindow("result")  # создаем главное окноcv2.namedWindow("settings")  # создаем окно настроекcap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# создаем 6 бегунков для настройки начального и конечного цвета фильтраcv2.createTrackbar('h1', 'settings', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('s1', 'settings', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('v1', 'settings', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('h2', 'settings', 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('s2', 'settings', 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('v2', 'settings', 255, 255, nothing)
crange = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

while True:
    flag, img = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # считываем значения бегунков    h1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('h1', 'settings')
    s1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('s1', 'settings')
    v1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('v1', 'settings')
    h2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('h2', 'settings')
    s2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('s2', 'settings')
    v2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('v2', 'settings')

    # формируем начальный и конечный цвет фильтра    h_min = np.array((h1, s1, v1), np.uint8)
    h_max = np.array((h2, s2, v2), np.uint8)

    # накладываем фильтр на кадр в модели HSV    thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, h_min, h_max)

    cv2.imshow('result', thresh)

    ch = cv2.waitKey(5)
    if ch == 27:
        breakcap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()````
`````

Comment: Typo error  breakcap.release() and where is VideoCapture(). Turn off lightning from.keyboard

Comment: Have you researched the problem yourself? What have you tried? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please review these recommendations and include the relevant information in the question.

Comment: paint a mask on your picture. then sample the pixels in that mask. now you know the range of colors of your object.

Comment: those two objects have different colors but ***only slightly different*** colors. there's enough noise and other perturbation to make this task near impossible. -- yes, the spectrum of light sources will affect how objects *appear*. objects themselves become light "sources". image sensor data is debayered and white-balanced. vital to understand in computer vision.